# export variable from class React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my app.js inside the app class there is a variable that I want to export to another module. I tried many options, but unfortunately, the understanding of how to do it correctly did not come. Tell me, please, how to do it right? Export default is already in use in my class

```
export class App extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        //somecode
    };

    constructor(...args: any): void {
        super(...args);
    }

    render() {
        // console.log('app render start');
        const test = true;
        return (
        //somecode
        );
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        //somecode
    }


    componentDidUpdate(prevProps): void {
        //somecode
    }
}
```

In the example above, i need to export variable 'test'

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Store test's value in state, pass state as a prop. Donezo!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assuming your intention with `test` is to define something like a "project constant" (which is what I gather, from your use of the `const` keyword), then you could simply declare `test` outside of the `App` class, and then export it from the module in the same way you are exporting the class:

App.js

```
/*
Export test variable
*/
export const test = true;

/*
Export your App class
*/
export class App extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        //somecode
    };

    constructor(...args: any): void {
        super(...args);
    }

    render() {
        /*
        Access test variable in "global scope" inside render method
        */
        console.log(`test is: ${ test }`);

        // console.log('app render start');
        // const test = true;
        return (
        //somecode
        );
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        //somecode
    }


    componentDidUpdate(prevProps): void {
        //somecode
    }
}
```

And then, from another module in your project you could access `test` like so:

MyModule.js

```
import { App, test, } from 'path/to/App';

console.log(`test is: ${ test }`);
```

Comment: Thanks, I managed to export a variable, but the problem is that the variable contains data that I cannot get outside of the class. in my particular case, I want to get an url by contacting it with a location.search, but outside the class I get an error ReferenceError: location is not defined

Comment: @A.Burdonskaya you're welcome - are you wanting to pass the `location.search` data to a javascript module outside of `app.js`?

Comment: Yes. I tried to access the location inside another module, but after unsuccessful attempts I decided to export a constant :c

Answer (score 2):

You could make test a static property on the App class, then just reference it from the App class since that is exported.

```js
class Test extends React.Component {
  static test = true;
}

console.info(Test.test);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

```
import Test from 'test';
console.info(Test.test);
```